# Why are fragment Directions not being generate for two fragments in different variants?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I have the situation where there are two build variants in an app. There are also two fragments with slightly different logic in those variants. The two fragments reside in different nav graphs for the variants.

Fragment One:

```
class GetStartedSignIn : Fragment(R.layout.some_layout) {
     private fun setupClickListeners() {
    binding.apply {
        loginAction.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(GetStartedSignInDirections.toLoginFragmentGetStarted())
        }
        signUpAction.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(GetStartedSignInDirections.toSignUpFragmentGetStarted())
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment Two:

```
class GetStartedSignIn : Fragment(R.layout.some_layout2) {
     private fun setupClickListeners() {
    binding.apply {
        loginAction.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(GetStartedSignInDirections.toLoginFragmentGetStarted())
        }
        signUpAction.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(GetStartedSignInDirections.toSignUpFragmentGetStarted())
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the first fragment:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to your project build.gradle

```
    ext{
      nav_version = "version_no"
    }
    dependencies{
      classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle- 
    plugin:$nav_version"
    }
```

add this on your build.gradle(app)

```
    plugins {
       id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    }
```